# BootstrapValidation is not working for me please see this code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add bootstrapvalidation to my website signup form but I'm not getting it to work need help please.
Here is the form code:

If any one can help me fix this I will be really greatful, Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tryitForm').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            firstName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            lastName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                    }
                }
            },
            gender: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The gender is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
            var fullName = [validator.getFieldElements('firstName').val(),
                            validator.getFieldElements('lastName').val()].join(' ');
            alert('Hello ' + fullName);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="tineyForym2" name="form1" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="user_id">
        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='edit' >
            <table   border="0" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="3" class="table" id='dynamic_form'>
                <tr>
                    <td class="dynamic_form_field">
                        <cite>*</cite>First Name
                    </td>
                    <td class="dynamic_form_value">
                        <input name="FirstName" class="form-control" value="" type="text" id="firstname" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Enter your First name!">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="dynamic_form_field">
                            <cite>*</cite>Last Name
                        </td>
                        <td class="dynamic_form_value">
                            <input name="LastName" class="form-control" value="" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Enter your last name!">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="dynamic_form_field" height="20">&nbsp; </td>
                            <td class="dynamic_form_value" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="dynamic_form_field">
                                <cite>*</cite>Username
                            </td>
                            <td class="dynamic_form_value">
                                <input name="Username" class="form-control" value="" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Username will be used for login purpose!">
                                    <br>(Choose Your username. Use letters, or numbers, but don't use spaces.)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="dynamic_form_field">
                                        <cite>*</cite>Password
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="dynamic_form_value">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="Password" value="" type="password" id="password" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Enter Login Password!">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="dynamic_form_field">
                                            <cite>*</cite>Confirm Password
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="dynamic_form_value">
                                            <input class="form-control" name="Password2" type="password" value="" id="password2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Enter Matching password">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="dynamic_form_field" height="20">&nbsp; </td>
                                            <td class="dynamic_form_value" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="dynamic_form_field">
                                                <cite>*</cite>Your E-mail
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="dynamic_form_value">
                                                <input class="form-control" name="Email" type="email" id="email" value="" id="email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Your Email Address">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="dynamic_form_field">Receive Newsletter </td>
                                                <td class="dynamic_form_value">
                                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                                        <input name="Newsletter" type="radio" value="1"  >Yes
                                                        </label>
                                                        <label class="radio-inline">
                                                            <input name="Newsletter" type="radio" value="0" >No
                                                            </label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="dynamic_form_field">Auto Notification on new Jobs </td>
                                                        <td class="dynamic_form_value">
                                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                <input name="Notification1" type="radio" value="1" >Yes
                                                                </label>
                                                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                                                    <input name="Notification1" type="radio" value="0" >No        
                                                                    </label>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                        <hr class="colorgraph">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                                                            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="dede" value="Submit">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> By clicking 
                                                                <strong class="label label-primary">Submit</strong>, you agree to the 
                                                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Terms and Conditions</a> set out by this site, including our Cookie Use.
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
```

And here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/eo5t48rw/5/

Comment: And.... what is not working according to you? Because we need general directions, we're not debugging whole pieces of code.

Comment: The validation part is not working, other thing works fine

Answer (score 0):

1. You should to use equal names for control names and for validator names.Ex.

   fields: {  firstName: { ...}, LastName { ...}, USERNAME {...} }

and controls should be named as name="firstName", name="LastName", name="USERNAME". Names are case sensitive!

2. for right using bootstrap validators you should use bootstrap document structure, like:

   ```
   <form id="tineyForym2" name="tineyForym2" method="post" class="form-vertical">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label"> First Name </label>
       <div class="controls">
         <input name="firstName" class="form-control" value="" type="text"  title="Enter your First name!" />
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label"> Last Name </label>
       <div class="controls">
         <input name="lastName" class="form-control" value="" type="text"  title="Enter your Last name!" />
       </div>
     </div>
   ```

   ...
3. I had js error "too much recursion" in your code . in line

   name="Email" type="email" id="email"

Rename this input control . it should not equal a type name (type="email")

4. in you example you init bootstrapValidator on nonexistent form element

   $('#tryitForm').bootstrapValidator

should be

```
$('#tineyForym2').bootstrapValidator
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The code is generated dynamically for some dynamic fields, so it is difficult to ad bootstrap document structure to it. I will try the code with these changes. Will revert back

Comment: You need to have <div class="form-group"> only in which has-error or has-success will be added by bootstrap validator. Your form should be working if you make changes as per seregaka and for sure you need to add form-group to visually see the results.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I will update this with form-group at jsfiddle and check if it works thanks for the help.

Comment: Update: I did the above changes sadly it isnt working here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eo5t48rw/24/

Comment: Ok it is working now, thanks: http://jsfiddle.net/eo5t48rw/29/ I would like to know how to display error using bootstapValidator in case of password mismatch. Thanks.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/eo5t48rw/33/ line 90 (i have added the callback feature). So Password2 now is `Password2: { validators: { notEmpty: { message: 'The matching password is required' }, callback: { message: 'The password should match', callback: function (value, validator) { return value == $("#password").val(); } } } }`